# Need button to go back and forward from value a to value b and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a button to display a temperature in Fahrenheit when click and return Celsius if clicked again and so on...

Here's what I have so far.

```
          $(".buttonToConvertToF").on("click", function() {

          $(".div3").text(Math.floor(temperature * 9 / 5 + 32) + "º Fahrenheit ");
          $(".div3").append("<i class='wi wi-" + dayOrNight + "-" + icon[weatherIconId].icon + "'></>");

          $(".div4").html("<button class='buttonToConvertToC btn btn-dark'>Convert to Celsius!</button>");




        });

        $(".buttonToConvertToC").on("click", function() {

          $(".div3").text(Math.floor(temperature) + "º Celsius ");
          $(".div3").append("<i class='wi wi-" + dayOrNight + "-" + icon[weatherIconId].icon + "'></>");

          $(".div4").html("<button class='buttonToConvertToF btn btn-outline-dark'>Convert to Fahrenheit!</button>");



        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation. With your approach jQuery will bind the events to the `.buttonToConvertToF` and `.buttonToConvertToF` at the moment of the first execution, but will not listen to the event on dynamically generated elements (like in your case).

Try the following implementation of event delegation:

```
// Delegate the event
$(document).on("click", ".buttonToConvertToF, .buttonToConvertToC", function() {

    // If the clicked element id ".buttonToConvertToF"
    if($(this).hasClass("buttonToConvertToF") {

        $(".div3").text(Math.floor(temperature * 9 / 5 + 32) + "º Fahrenheit ");
        $(".div3").append("<i class='wi wi-" + dayOrNight + "-" + icon[weatherIconId].icon + "'></>");
        $(".div4").html("<button class='buttonToConvertToC btn btn-dark'>Convert to Celsius!</button>");

    } else { // The other button

        $(".div3").text(Math.floor(temperature) + "º Celsius ");
        $(".div3").append("<i class='wi wi-" + dayOrNight + "-" + icon[weatherIconId].icon + "'></>");
        $(".div4").html("<button class='buttonToConvertToF btn btn-outline-dark'>Convert to Fahrenheit!</button>");

    }

});
```

Comment: Is there a better way to approach this situation?

Comment: @JorgeMouta you should also post the html to see if there is a better option. If it solved your issue please mark it as the valid answer please :-)